# Method returns null / If statement not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, helper

**UPDATED:**

Ok, I just found out my first if in my method isn't working.
This one:

```
if ($codigo == null) {
    # Stuff 
} else {
    #other stuff
}
```

But I also don't know whats wrong.

**PREVIOUS:**

I have an observer watching the event `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after`. But when I try to call a method from my helper Data.php, it returns null.

This is my observer:

```
public function stockUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    # Produto
    $event = $observer->getEvent()->getItem()->getProduct();

    if ($event->getAllnationsSync() == 1) {
        $control = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/id_allnations', Mage::app()->getStore());

        $id = $event->getData($control);
        Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->updateStock($id);
    }
}
```

And this is my method:

```
public static function updateStock($codigo = null)
{
    try {
        # Força o load da página em modo ADMIN
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

        # Pega usuario e senha colocados na config
        $apiUser = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/api_user', Mage::app()->getStore());
        $apiPassword = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/api_password', Mage::app()->getStore());

        # Model da integração, para pegar a data da ultima atualização
        $integration = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/integration');

        $productIntegration = $integration->load(2);
        $integration = $integration->load(3);

        # Checa qual é maior, se é a data da integração dos produtos ou da atualização
        if ($integration->getUpdatedAt() < $productIntegration->getUpdatedAt()) {
            $updatedAt = substr($integration->getUpdatedAt(), 0, 9);
        } else {
            $updatedAt = substr($productIntegration->getUpdatedAt(), 0, 9);
        }

        # Verifica qual o atributo que representa o ID da All Nations
        $control = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/id_allnations', Mage::app()->getStore());

        # Instancia o model de estoque
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');

        # Variavel de controle
        $success = 0;

        # Se for chamado sem o parametro $codigo, atualiza todos os produtos
        if ($codigo == null) {
            $ANProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('allnations_sync', ['eq' => 1]);

            foreach ($ANProducts as $single) {
                $id = $single->getData($control); // Pega o ID da All Nations
                $url = 'url' .
                    '?CodigoCliente=' . $apiUser .
                    '&Senha=' . $apiPassword .
                    '&CodigoProduto=' . $id .
                    '&Data=' . $updatedAt;

                $return = Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->callCurl('GET', $url);
                $httpCode = $return['httpCode']['httpCode'];

                $return = $return['response']['diffgrdiffgram']['NewDataSet']['Estoques'];

                if ($httpCode == '200') {

                    if ($return['CODIGO'] == $single->getData($control)) {

                        if ($single->getData('allnations_promo') == 0) {
                            $single->setPrice
                            ($return['PRECOREVENDA']);
                        } else {
                            $single->setSpecialPrice
                            ($return['PRECOREVENDA']);
                        }

                        $single->save();

                        $stock = $stockItem->loadByProduct($single->getId());
                        $stock->setQty($return['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL']);
                        $stock->setIsInStock($return['DISPONIVEL']);

                        $stock->save();

                        if ($success != 1) {
                            $success = 1;
                        };
                    }
                } else {
                    return $httpCode;
                }
            }

            if ($success == 1) {
                $firstUpdate = $integration->getData('first_update');

                # Checa se ja foi atualizado antes
                if (!$firstUpdate) {
                    $integration->setFirstUpdate(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                    $integration->setUpdatedAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                    $integration->save();
                } else {
                    $integration->setUpdatedAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                    $integration->save();
                }

                return $httpCode;
            }
        } else {

            $url = 'url' .
                '?CodigoCliente=' . $apiUser .
                '&Senha=' . $apiPassword .
                '&CodigoProduto=' . $codigo .
                '&Data=' . $updatedAt;

            $return = Mage::helper('novapc_allnations')->callCurl('GET', $url);
            $httpCode = $return['httpCode']['httpCode'];

            if ($httpCode == '200') {

                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->loadByAttribute($control, $codigo);


                if ($return['CODIGO'] == $product->getData($control)) {

                    if ($product->getData('allnations_promo') == 0) {
                        $product->setPrice
                        ($return['PRECOREVENDA']);
                    } else {
                        $product->setSpecialPrice
                        ($return['PRECOREVENDA']);
                    }

                    $product->save();

                    $stock = $stockItem->loadByProduct($product->getId());
                    $stock->setQty($return['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL']);
                    $stock->setIsInStock($return['DISPONIVEL']);

                    $stock->save();

                    return $httpCode;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Novapc_Allnations>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Novapc_Allnations>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations>
                        <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>confirmReserve</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
            <sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations>
                        <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>stockUpdate</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
            <admin_system_config_section_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations>
                        <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setAttributes</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations>
                </observers>
            </admin_system_config_section_save_after>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations>
                        <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>updatePromotions</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations_order>
                        <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>updateOrderStatus</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations_order>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations>
                        <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkOrder</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
        <resources>
            <novapc_allnations_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Novapc_Allnations</module>
                    <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </novapc_allnations_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Block</class>
            </novapc_allnations>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Helper</class>
            </novapc_allnations>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>novapc_allnations_resource</resourceModel>
            </novapc_allnations>
            <novapc_allnations_resource>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <order>
                        <table>npcallnations_orders</table>
                    </order>
                    <integration>
                        <table>npcallnations_integrations</table>
                    </integration>
                    <promotion>
                        <table>npcallnations_promotions</table>
                    </promotion>
                    <attr>
                        <table>npcallnations_attributes</table>
                    </attr>
                </entities>
            </novapc_allnations_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <novapc_allnations>
            <general>
                <status>1</status>
            </general>
        </novapc_allnations>
    </default>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <novapc_allnations>
                    <file>novapc_allnations.xml</file>
                </novapc_allnations>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Novapc_Allnations>
                    <files>
                        <default>Novapc_Allnations.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Novapc_Allnations>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <global_search>
            <promotion>
                <class>novapc_allnations/adminhtml_search_promotion</class>
                <acl>novapc_allnations</acl>
            </promotion>
        </global_search>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <allnations>
                                            <title>Allnations - All</title>
                                        </allnations>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Novapc_Allnations before="Mage_Adminhtml">Novapc_Allnations_Adminhtml</Novapc_Allnations>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <allnations_promot>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 */4 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>novapc_allnations/observer::deletePromotions</model>
                </run>
            </allnations_promot>
            <allnations_stockupdate>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr></cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>novapc_allnations/observer::updateStock</model>
                </run>
            </allnations_stockupdate>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Comment: is your helper function calling properly?

Comment: I think so. This function works fine when I call from other places. I call it from a grid and it works. It just doesn't work in this observer

Comment: if your function works fine then,  `$id = $event->getData($control);` did you check ID?

Comment: yes, that worked too. I tried to add that to a custom table and the correct value was added

Comment: remove the `static` word from your function and then try

Comment: still nothing... and now the product is not being added to the cart

Comment: Please share your `config.xml`

Comment: @Prince just updated it

Comment: What returns the `var_dump($id);` in observer?

Comment: what value give by `$control` and `$id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

**1b.** If you need to add attribute which name you know in advance, add it in your config.xml under `global/sales/quote/item/product_attributes` add your attribute like this (see `Mage\Sales\etc\config.xml` for an example):

```
<ext_id/>
```

**1b.** Or add programmatically, subscribe to event `sales_quote_config_get_product_attributes` and add your attribute to attributes object. Check out `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Observer::addProductAttributes` for an example.

**2.** Ensure your attribute is included in product listing, so that it's present in flat tables. Edit attribute in admin panel and check `Used in Product Listing: Yes`.

**Background:**

Reason for this is that your custom attribute is not loaded on product.

Stock items are loaded as part or quote, like this:

- $quote->getAllVisibleItems()
- Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::_afterLoad - _assignProducts
- Quote_Item_Abstract->checkData()
- Quote_Item->setQty()

Normally we would only have raw quote items without actual products, only product_id. But Magento cares for us and loads all referenced products in _assignProducts.
With a view to optimization, only important attributes are loaded:

\Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::_assignProducts

```
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addIdFilter($this->_productIds)
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addOptionsToResult()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->addTierPriceData();
```

A place of interest here is getProductAttributes():

```
const XML_PATH_QUOTE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES = 'global/sales/quote/item/product_attributes';

public function getProductAttributes()
{
    $attributes = Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_QUOTE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES)->asArray();
    $transfer = new Varien_Object($attributes);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_config_get_product_attributes', array('attributes' => $transfer));
    $attributes = $transfer->getData();
    return array_keys($attributes);
}
```

So it loads only attributes, that are defined in everywhere in config.xml at path 'global/sales/quote/item/product_attributes'. Additionally you can add custom ones in event `sales_quote_config_get_product_attributes`.
Mage\Sales\etc\config.xml for example containes these:

```
                <product_attributes>
                    <sku/>
                    <type_id/>
                    <name/>
                    <status/>
                    <visibility/>
                    <price/>
                    <weight/>
                    <url_path/>
                    <url_key/>
                    <thumbnail/>
                    <small_image/>
                    <tax_class_id/>
                    <special_from_date/>
                    <special_to_date/>
                    <special_price/>
                    <cost/>
                    <is_recurring/>
                    <recurring_profile/>
                    <gift_message_available/>
                    <msrp_enabled/>
                    <msrp/>
                    <msrp_display_actual_price_type/>
                </product_attributes>
```

**Additional considerations**

I'm a bit worried that your observer will fire too often even when qty is not actually changed - quoteItem->setQty() is called on every quote load.

This includes plainly browsing website when you have something in your cart - main page, categories, checkout etc. E.g. open main page:

- quote.getAllVisibleItems
- Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::_afterLoad - _assignProducts
- Quote_Item_Abstract.checkData
- Quote_Item.setQty

Answer (score 0):

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Novapc_Allnations>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Novapc_Allnations>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Block</class>
            </novapc_allnations>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Helper</class>
            </novapc_allnations>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <novapc_allnations>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>novapc_allnations_resource</resourceModel>
            </novapc_allnations>
            <novapc_allnations_resource>
                <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <order>
                        <table>npcallnations_orders</table>
                    </order>
                    <integration>
                        <table>npcallnations_integrations</table>
                    </integration>
                    <promotion>
                        <table>npcallnations_promotions</table>
                    </promotion>
                    <attr>
                        <table>npcallnations_attributes</table>
                    </attr>
                </entities>
            </novapc_allnations_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <novapc_allnations_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Novapc_Allnations</module>
                    <class>Novapc_Allnations_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </novapc_allnations_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations_reserve>
                        <class>novapc_allnations/observer</class>
                        <method>confirmReserve</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations_reserve>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
            <sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations_update>
                        <class>novapc_allnations/observer</class>
                        <method>stockUpdate</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations_update>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations_order>
                        <class>novapc_allnations/observer</class>
                        <method>checkOrder</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
            <admin_system_config_section_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations_attribute>
                        <class>novapc_allnations/observer</class>
                        <method>setAttributes</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations_attribute>
                </observers>
            </admin_system_config_section_save_after>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations_promotion>
                        <class>novapc_allnations/observer</class>
                        <method>updatePromotions</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations_promotion>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <novapc_allnations_orderstatus>
                        <class>novapc_allnations/observer</class>
                        <method>updateOrderStatus</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </novapc_allnations_orderstatus>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <novapc_allnations>
            <general>
                <status>1</status>
            </general>
        </novapc_allnations>
    </default>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <novapc_allnations>
                    <file>novapc_allnations.xml</file>
                </novapc_allnations>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Novapc_Allnations>
                    <files>
                        <default>Novapc_Allnations.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Novapc_Allnations>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <global_search>
            <promotion>
                <class>novapc_allnations/adminhtml_search_promotion</class>
                <acl>novapc_allnations</acl>
            </promotion>
        </global_search>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <allnations>
                                            <title>Allnations - All</title>
                                        </allnations>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Novapc_Allnations before="Mage_Adminhtml">Novapc_Allnations_Adminhtml</Novapc_Allnations>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <allnations_promot>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 */4 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>novapc_allnations/observer::deletePromotions</model>
                </run>
            </allnations_promot>
            <allnations_stockupdate>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr></cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>novapc_allnations/observer::updateStock</model>
                </run>
            </allnations_stockupdate>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Comment: not working....

Comment: in your observer, are you sure that you get something from the id ? try this `Mage::log($event->getData($control));`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I tried adding the `$id` value to a random table I have and it worked fine. Here https://i.imgur.com/IkopQo8.png I updated my question, the issue is my IF statement in helper

Comment: replace `public static function updateStock($codigo = null)` with `public function updateStock($codigo = 0)`

Comment: with `$codigo = 0` it wouldn't work, so I tried with an empty string `''` and it also doesn't work

Comment: and this `public function updateStock($codigo)`, please add this and tell me what you see `var_dump($event->getData($control));` in your observer

Comment: have you tried if (!$codigo || $codigo=='') ?